# How to model a more limited version of class with shared code?

Tags: swift, parameters, liskov-substitution-principle

I need to create a new class. Some of its functionality is already in another class and from a domain standpoint it makes sense to inherit from it. The problem is that there is a method which has to be more limited in its parameter type, because of LSP (Liskov substitution principle) you can not overwrite it.

Until now there is code, which I may change,

For better explanation let me make an easy example:

I have `AnimalShelter` and I need to implement `DogShelter`.

```
class AnimalShelter {
    func usefulMethod(...) {}

    func take(x: Animal) {}
}

class DogShelter {
    var dogMedianCuteness: String = "normal (= very cute)"

    func usefulMethod(...) {}

    func take(x: Dog) {}
}
```

#### Solution 1: Subclass

If `DogShelter` is a subclass of `AnimalShelter` then it will get the `usefulMethod(...)` for free, but the inherited method `take(x: Animal)` can not be overridden and pollutes the API of DogShelter and should just do nothing or throw an error.

```
class AnimalShelter {
    func usefulMethod(...) {}

    func take(x: Animal) {}
}

class DogShelter: AnimalShelter {
    var dogMedianCuteness: String = "normal (= very cute)"

    func take(x: Dog) {}
}
```

#### Solution 2: Protocol + protocol extension

If `AnimalShelter` and `DogShelter` implement a protocol, it is not precise from a domain standpoint, but the shared code `usefulMethod(...)` can be implemented in a **protocol** `extension`.

```
protocol UsefulThing {
    func usefulMethod(...)
}

extension UsefulThing {
    func usefulMethod(...) { ... }
}

class AnimalShelter: UsefulThing {
    func take(x: Animal) {}
}

class DogShelter: UsefulThing {
    var dogMedianCuteness: String = "normal (= very cute)"

    func take(x: Dog) {}
}
```

#### Solution 3: Generalization, create another superclass

The problem is the `take(x: T)` method which is more specialized in `DogShelter`. Taking it away from AnimalShelter will allow to inherit without problems, but everything that used AnimalShelter until now has to be replaced by a new subclass `AnyAnimalShelter: AnimalShelter` which has the problematic `take(x: Animal) {}`

```
class AnimalShelter {
    usefulMethod(...) {}
}

class AnyAnimalShelter: AnimalShelter {
    take(x: Animal) {}
}

class DogShelter: AnimalShelter  {
    var dogMedianCuteness: String = "normal (= very cute)"

    func take(x: Dog) {}
}
```

#### Solution 4: Composition

Inheritance does make sense from the domain's view, therefore boss finds it best to keep.

---

So I got the code from `AnimalShelter` and am allowed to change it, even though it will rise eyebrows why I would change code that is running perfectly for years. I need an abstract reason about what about the `take(x: Animal)` method is flawed in `AnimalShelter`. Not only to have good reasoning against it but also to avoid it in future classes.

It would be a real problem if I could not change code that **uses** `AnimalShelter` or `AnimalShelter` itself.

### Question

How should someone/I model it?

Comment: As you correctly identified, this violates LSV, so `DogShelter` should be unrelated to `AnimalShelter`. What about a `Shelter<T>` class that allows `Shelter<Dog>` and `Shelter<Animal>` and so on?

Comment: @Sweeper That is indeed for the given example the best solution. But there may be properties/methods/protocol inheritance that are only in the `DogShelter` class, for example a `bite()` method, where would you put those then?

Comment: As long as they are not stored properties (I.e. methods and computed properties etc are all ok), you can put them in extensions.

Comment: @Sweeper Of course I have such a thing as a stored property in the project that this example is related to. Added it to the example to reflect that. Maybe there is still a way to use generics, have to think about it.

Comment: What about a protocol `Shelter` with an associated type `AnimalType` that `DogShelter` and `AnimalShelter` conform to? Do you need to use `Shelter` as a type anywhere?

Comment: @Sweeper It did work. Posted solution. Thank you. If you write an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a protocol with an associated type:

```
protocol Shelter {
    associatedtype AnimalType

    func take(x: AnimalType)
}

extension Shelter {
    func usefulMethod(...)
}

class AnimalShelter : Shelter {
    typealias AnimalType = Animal
    func take(x: Animal) { ... }
}

class DogShelter : Shelter {
    typealias AnimalType = Dog
    var dogMedianCuteness: String = "normal (= very cute)"
    func take(x: Dog) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution suggested by Sweeper.

```
class Animal {}
class Dog: Animal {}
```

Use generics + class extensions with type constraints (where clause) when not having any stored properties.

```
class AnimalShelter<T: Animal> {
    func usefulMethod(...) {}

    func take(x: T) {}
}
```

Else use solution 2: protocols, protocol extensions and add an associated type to the protocol with the corresponding type limitation in each class.

```
protocol Shelter {
    var animalType: Any.Type { get }

    func usefulMethod() -> String
}

extension Shelter {
    func usefulMethod() -> String {
        return "useful"
    }
}

class AnimalShelter: Shelter {
    let animalType: Any.Type = Animal.self

    func take(x: animalType) {}
}

class DogShelter: Shelter {
    let animalType: Any.Type = Dog.self

    var dogMedianCuteness: String = "normal (= very cute)"

    func take(x: animalType) {}
}
```